# Socket in Python3, listening port

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I want to listen port in Python3.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print 'connected:', addr

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

The data which I want to listen, looks like:

```
8,0,0,test,0,2016/07/19,14:40:57.938,2016/07/19,14:40:57.938,,,,,,,,,,,,0
8,0,0,test,0,2016/07/19,14:40:57.965,2016/07/19,14:40:57.965,,,,,,,,,,,,0
3,0,0,test,0,2016/07/19,14:41:04.687,2016/07/19,14:41:04.687,,2475,,,,,,,,,,0
..
```

that is I need read until `'\n'`
So I need to change this block, but I dont know how..

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
if not data:
    break
conn.send(data.upper())
```

I want replace nc:

```
nc -k -l -p 30003 | python3 script.py
```

where script.py

```
while True:
    for string in sys.stdin:
```

Also I need reconnect if something wrong, server must be ready take all data any time, just like `nc -k -l -p 30003 | python3 script.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is to read until you find `\n` character in your stream. Of course `\n` may be beyond `1024` bytes that you are reading thus you need to store everything you read in a buffer. This can be emulated with for example such class:

```
class SocketLineReader:
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self._buffer = b''

    def readline(self):
        pre, separator, post = self._buffer.partition(b'\n')
        if separator:
            self._buffer = post
            return pre + separator

        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                return None

            pre, separator, post = data.partition(b'\n')
            if not separator:
                self._buffer += data
            else:
                data = self._buffer + pre + separator
                self._buffer = post
                return data
```

And usage:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

reader = SocketLineReader(conn)
while True:
    data = reader.readline()
    print(data)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

---

If you wish for the server to serve data forever use another `while` loop:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('connected:', addr)
    reader = SocketLineReader(conn)
    # The other code goes here
```

The problem with this approach is that there is no parallelism. Your server won't handle parallel connections. One way to fix that is to send each new connection to a separate thread:

```
import socket
import threading

def handle(conn):
    print('connected:', addr)
    reader = SocketLineReader(conn)
    # The other code goes here

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(conn,)).start()
```

This should be fine until you hit performance limit. There are ways to improve efficiency (e.g. event loops) but I supposes it's beyond this question.

Comment: It's absolutly what I want.
But there is some trouble: when I connect first time:
 `nc localhost port
Ctrl+C
`
and the script finished.

Is it possible to modify it to working all time?
Thanks.

Comment: @user7365441 You just have to tell your listening socket to `accept` forever (i.e. in a `while` loop). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you!